# Raw read the boot sector with fstream

Tags: c++

```
fstream file("G:", ios::in | ios::binary);

unsigned char buffer[512];

file.read((char *)buffer, 512);

file.close();

cout << buffer <<"\n";
```

I want to raw read the boot sector from my flash drive.
Can i use for this job fstream?

Comment: Can you advice me something ?

Comment: Just because your question may be a bad question does not mean you should edit it to garbage eradMan.

Comment: @MM. - that's not really true.  The primary issue not the function used to access the data, but rather finding a file-like raw device.  On a Unix-style OS that's trivial (though there may be a permission roadblock), on other OS's it may or may not be possible.

Comment: That's where you are wrong.  You do not need anything beyond standard i/o functions, if the machine has a raw device "file" and your user has permissions to it.  Your program can interact with the raw disk just like with any other file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File stream operations are written to access *files*. The [CPP Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/) does not further specify what a 'file' is in this context -- and maybe they are right. After all, it *highly* depends on the OS what's considered a 'file'.

However: under none of these interpretations is the boot sector a file. You cannot see or read the boot sector in Windows Explorer or OS X Finder -- it's "above and beyond" the level of *files*.

Your test program fails because "G:" is not interpreted as 'a flash drive', but merely as 'a full path specification'. When working on the level of "boot sectors", there *are* no paths and drive letter assignments. You are working with physical objects instead: actual disks, and actual sectors.

See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28314/Reading-and-Writing-to-Raw-Disk-Sectors for a first taste of raw reading.

Comment: Well, physical drives _are_ files on every modern OS. The problem of accessing them is merely one of knowing the correct name, and having administrative rights. `G:` suggests that the OP is using Windows, so something like `\\.\PhysicalDrive2"` (assuming there's one harddisk and a cdrom) should do the trick. Of course ideally one would want to query the correct name instead of looking into the crystal ball (article on MSDN about how to do that).